# How to decode array in array JSON?

Tags: json, swift

I can't get all elements of my array. I think the problem is in my Model, but i don't know how to correct it.
The following JSON is given:

```
    {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "content": [
        {
            "description": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "First",
                    "cost": 200,
                    "count": 1
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "Second",
                    "cost": 500,
                    "count": 1
                }
            },
            "sum": 700,
            "created_at": "13.11.2018 17:22"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Model:

```
// MARK: - History
struct History: Codable {
    let statusCode: Int
    let message: String
    let content: [History_Content]
}

// MARK: - Content
struct History_Content: Codable {
    let description: [String: History_Description]
    let sum: Int
    let created_at: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description
        case sum
        case created_at
    }
}

// MARK: - Description
struct History_Description: Codable {
    let name: String
    let cost, count: Int
}
```

My cellForRowAt :

```
var arrData = [History_Content](). 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "history_cell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell
        
        cell.time.text = arrData[indexPath.row].created_at
        for i in arrData[indexPath.row].description.self{
            cell.desc.text = "You bought \"\(i.value.name)\""

        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

I just get a single element of description. How can i get all elements of this array? What do i need to change in my code?

Comment: description is dictionary not array ...

Comment: What do you do after the decoding, what do you assign to `arrData`?

Comment: Change `let description: [String: History_Description]` (dictionary) to `let description: [History_Description]` (array)

Comment: @Deitsch Bad advice since it's a dictionary

Comment: Deitsch, i tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: try this site: https://app.quicktype.io If i fail to do it myself i try to find the mistake comparing it.

Comment: @Deitsch There is nothing wrong with the struct's

Comment: Just checked myself, was focused on his selfdiagnose `problem is in my model`. Guess we need to know what assigned to `arrData` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge `name` of all values you can do

```
let row = arrData[indexPath.row]
cell.desc.text = "You bought \(row.description.values.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: ", "))"
```

But if the order is important you can sort first, here I sort by key

```
let sorted = row.description.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
cell.desc.text = "You bought \(sorted.map { $0.value.name }.joined(separator: ", "))"
```

Comment: Thank you. This code works like @erik_m_martens, but takes less characters

Answer (score 1):

```swift
for i in arrData[indexPath.row].description.self{
   cell.desc.text = "You bought \"\(i.value.name)\""
}
```

You are iterating over each value of the `description`-dictionary and setting the contents to `cell.desc.text`. However each time you set the `cell.desc.text` in your `for`-loop you override the previously assigned value.

What do you want to achieve here for the `cell.desc.text`? A comma-separated list? Then you should do something like this:

```swift
var cellDescr = "You bought"
for i in arrData[indexPath.row].description.self {
    cellDescr.append(" \"\(i.value.name)\",")
}
cell.desc.text = cellDescr.trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters) // remove dangling comma
```

Let me know if this helps or you want to achieve something else and I will update my answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working
That is what i needed